# Scipy "masked arrays are not supported" error

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, pykalman

I am trying to calibrate a model using pykalman and the scipy optimiser. For some reasons scipy seem to think that my input is a masked array, but it is not. I have added the code below:

```
    k =  0.00000000000001 #small sarting value
    T = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5] , dtype=int) #maturities
    delta = 1e-9
    x = k
    transition_covariance=delta / (1 - delta) * np.eye(1)
    
    
    def obj(x):
        k = x[0]
        Q = (1 - k) *np.eye(1)
        Z = np.exp(-k*T)
        Z =Z[:, None] #reshape to 2 dim
        transition_covariance=delta / (1 - delta) * np.eye(1)
    
        observation_covariance=0.001*np.eye(len(T))
    
        
        kf = KalmanFilter(transition_matrices=np.eye(1)*(1-k),
                      observation_matrices= Z,
                      transition_covariance=transition_covariance,
                      observation_covariance=observation_covariance)
    
        lk =  kf.loglikelihood(X) # X is my observed data, 1265 rows × 5 columns
        return -lk
    
    x = np.array([k])
    
    k =scipy.optimize.minimize(obj, x, method= 'TNC')
```

Running the scipy optimiser I get the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-8d87c9f2ced0> in <module>
      1 # method that works: TNC, Nelder-Mead
----> 2 k =scipy.optimize.minimize(obj, x, method= 'TNC')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minimize.py in minimize(fun, x0, args, method, jac, hess, hessp, bounds, constraints, tol, callback, options)
    618                                 callback=callback, **options)
    619     elif meth == 'tnc':
--> 620         return _minimize_tnc(fun, x0, args, jac, bounds, callback=callback,
    621                              **options)
    622     elif meth == 'cobyla':

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\tnc.py in _minimize_tnc(fun, x0, args, jac, bounds, eps, scale, offset, mesg_num, maxCGit, maxiter, eta, stepmx, accuracy, minfev, ftol, xtol, gtol, rescale, disp, callback, finite_diff_rel_step, maxfun, **unknown_options)
    373         messages = MSG_NONE
    374 
--> 375     sf = _prepare_scalar_function(fun, x0, jac=jac, args=args, epsilon=eps,
    376                                   finite_diff_rel_step=finite_diff_rel_step,
    377                                   bounds=new_bounds)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py in _prepare_scalar_function(fun, x0, jac, args, bounds, epsilon, finite_diff_rel_step, hess)
    259     # ScalarFunction caches. Reuse of fun(x) during grad
    260     # calculation reduces overall function evaluations.
--> 261     sf = ScalarFunction(fun, x0, args, grad, hess,
    262                         finite_diff_rel_step, bounds, epsilon=epsilon)
    263 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_differentiable_functions.py in __init__(self, fun, x0, args, grad, hess, finite_diff_rel_step, finite_diff_bounds, epsilon)
     74 
     75         self._update_fun_impl = update_fun
---> 76         self._update_fun()
     77 
     78         # Gradient evaluation

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_differentiable_functions.py in _update_fun(self)
    164     def _update_fun(self):
    165         if not self.f_updated:
--> 166             self._update_fun_impl()
    167             self.f_updated = True
    168 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_differentiable_functions.py in update_fun()
     71 
     72         def update_fun():
---> 73             self.f = fun_wrapped(self.x)
     74 
     75         self._update_fun_impl = update_fun

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_differentiable_functions.py in fun_wrapped(x)
     68         def fun_wrapped(x):
     69             self.nfev += 1
---> 70             return fun(x, *args)
     71 
     72         def update_fun():

<ipython-input-13-48731c614f15> in obj(x)
     19                   observation_covariance=observation_covariance)
     20 
---> 21     lk =  kf.loglikelihood(X) # X is my observed data, 1016 rows × 17 columns
     22     return -lk

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pykalman\standard.py in loglikelihood(self, X)
   1470 
   1471         # get likelihoods for each time step
-> 1472         loglikelihoods = _loglikelihoods(
   1473           observation_matrices, observation_offsets, observation_covariance,
   1474           predicted_state_means, predicted_state_covariances, Z

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pykalman\standard.py in _loglikelihoods(observation_matrices, observation_offsets, observation_covariance, predicted_state_means, predicted_state_covariances, observations)
    165                 + observation_covariance
    166             )
--> 167             loglikelihoods[t] = log_multivariate_normal_density(
    168                 observation[np.newaxis, :],
    169                 predicted_observation_mean[np.newaxis, :],

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pykalman\utils.py in log_multivariate_normal_density(X, means, covars, min_covar)
     71                                       lower=True)
     72         cv_log_det = 2 * np.sum(np.log(np.diagonal(cv_chol)))
---> 73         cv_sol = solve_triangular(cv_chol, (X - mu).T, lower=True).T
     74         log_prob[:, c] = - .5 * (np.sum(cv_sol ** 2, axis=1) + \
     75                                      n_dim * np.log(2 * np.pi) + cv_log_det)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\basic.py in solve_triangular(a, b, trans, lower, unit_diagonal, overwrite_b, debug, check_finite)
    332 
    333     a1 = _asarray_validated(a, check_finite=check_finite)
--> 334     b1 = _asarray_validated(b, check_finite=check_finite)
    335     if len(a1.shape) != 2 or a1.shape[0] != a1.shape[1]:
    336         raise ValueError('expected square matrix')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\_lib\_util.py in _asarray_validated(a, check_finite, sparse_ok, objects_ok, mask_ok, as_inexact)
    259     if not mask_ok:
    260         if np.ma.isMaskedArray(a):
--> 261             raise ValueError('masked arrays are not supported')
    262     toarray = np.asarray_chkfinite if check_finite else np.asarray
    263     a = toarray(a)

ValueError: masked arrays are not supported
```

Maybe something to do with an update in the scipy library? It worked with a different setup, so that's all I can think. My versions are:
Python 3.8.5
Scipy 1.5.2
Pykalman 0.9.5

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution, which involves a small change in the utils.py file in the pykalman library (line 73):

```
        try:
            cv_sol = solve_triangular(cv_chol, (X - mu).T, lower=True).T
        except ValueError:
            cv_sol = np.linalg.solve(cv_chol, (X - mu).T).T
```

Source:
https://github.com/pykalman/pykalman/issues/83

Answer (score 0):

I was following [this blog post](https://gtezio.medium.com/commodity-pricing-how-do-you-actually-do-it-fac34a0b7e08) and ran into the same error.

The solution I found in [this Github comment](https://github.com/pykalman/pykalman/issues/83#issuecomment-1725339763) was to uninstall `pykalman` and install [`pykalman-bardo`](https://github.com/pybardo/pykalman). The code in the blog post then executes unchanged.